# How can I combine multiple combineReducers functions in Redux using something like immutable.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am using immutable.JS to manage my stores via redux-immutablejs. I would now like to use the redux-form library but I am having an issue combining reducers.

Redux-immutable provides a combineReducers function that will check if all the reducers it is passed return immutable objects.

Redux itself provides a combineReducers function that performs no such checking.

Redux-form requires that you include their reducers but I cannot do so using Redux immutable's combineReducers as it will fail.

So what I'm trying to do is basically combine the outputs of these two functions like so:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { combineReducers as combineReducersUtils } from 'redux-utils';
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';

const mainReducers = combineReducersUtils({
  devices, alarms
});

const extraReducers = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer
});

export default (mainReducers + extraReducers);
```

The last line obviously doesn't work but illustrates basically what I'm after.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Sorry just to be clear combineReducers from redux-utils is a lightweight wrapper around redux-immutable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
function rootReducer(state, action) {
  const newState = combineReducersUtils({devices, alarms})(state, action);
  return combineReducers({form: formReducer})(newState, action);
}
```

It should work because the return value of combineReducers is just a reducer:

> (Function): A reducer that invokes every reducer inside the reducers object, and constructs a state object with the same shape.

https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/docs/api/combineReducers.md

---

Updated to not create a new function on every dispatch:

```
const mainReducers = combineReducersUtils({devices, alarms});
const formReducers = combineReducers({form: formReducer});

function rootReducer(state, action) {
  return formReducers(mainReducers(state, action), action);
}
```

Comment: Just for anyone reading this in the future this is now fully documented as part of redux-form here http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/faq/immutable-js?_k=dqesvr

Comment: This would have a pretty bad performance because you are allocating a function every time an action is dispatched.

Comment: @DanAbramov is there a better way? I have some shared fields (ie page number, sort type) and I don't want to duplicate logic in different reducers

Comment: @user3409950 Please ask a separate question about Redux Form specifically. I don’t quite understand the question.